# Elasticsearch - SearchHit - how to set hits?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How I can establish more then 10 hits (SearchHit) in SearchResponse?
By default I have only 10 hits and can't get more.
When I do searchResponse.getHits(), I get only 10 hits.

Comment: Could you please provide the code with which you are trying

Answer (score 0):

By default any ES query will give back only 10 recors ,you can control this by the size

You can simple put size(no_ofrecords_you want_in single hit)

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 100,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```